# How is the table RDF_PREFIX used in Virtuoso?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, triplestore, virtuoso

Virtuoso stores RDF triples in the `RDF_QUAD` table. In this table, IRIs are stored as `IRI_ID`'s datatype and the values are stored in `RDF_IRI` table. But I don't understand the use of the `RDF_PREFIX` table. Is it to reduce the used space of `RDF_IRI` table? But how is the join done? (The `RDF_PREFIX` table has a integer key).  The documentation doesn't explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context (which, admittedly doesn't explain why there are two tables rather than just one) the [documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfdatarepresentation.html) says:

> ```
> create table DB.DBA.RDF_PREFIX (
>   RP_NAME varchar primary key,
>   RP_ID int not null unique );
> create table DB.DBA.RDF_IRI (
>   RI_NAME varchar primary key,
>   RI_ID IRI_ID not null unique );
> ```
>
> These two tables store a mapping between internal IRI id's and their external string form. A memory-resident cache contains recently used IRIs to reduce access to this table. Function id_to_iri (in id IRI_ID) returns the IRI by its ID. Function iri_to_id (in iri varchar, in may_create_new_id) returns an IRI_ID for given string; if the string is not used before as an IRI then either NULL is returned or a new ID is allocated, depending on the second argument.

Notice that the `RP_ID` of `RDF_PREFIX` is an `int`, whereas the `RI_ID` of `RDF_IRI` is an `IRI_ID`.  Even though they both have `varchar` primary keys, the IDs to which they map those names are not the same type.  In fact, it appears is appears that even though the primary key of `RDF_IRI` is a varchar, it isn't the *same kind* of varchar as that in `RDF_PREFIX`.  The following example shows this, I think. [Example 1.5.44 How can I perform search for predicate values](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtuosotipsandtricks.html#srchprd) from the documentation gives an example of its use. I'm not enough of a SQL'er to say exactly what's *happening* in that example, but it might be a good start to see how `RDF_PREFIX` gets used.  Here's a snippet from that example:

```
  for ( SELECT RP_NAME, RP_ID 
        FROM RDF_PREFIX
        WHERE (RP_NAME >= path) AND (RP_NAME < path || chr(255)) ) do
    {
      declare fourbytes varchar;
      fourbytes := '----';
      fourbytes[0] := bit_shift (RP_ID, -24);
      fourbytes[1] := bit_and (bit_shift (RP_ID, -16), 255);
      fourbytes[2] := bit_and (bit_shift (RP_ID, -8), 255);
      fourbytes[3] := bit_and (RP_ID, 255);

      for ( SELECT RI_NAME, RI_ID from RDF_IRI
            WHERE (RI_NAME >= fourbytes) AND (RI_NAME < fourbytes || chr(255)) ) do
        {
          if (exists (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM RDF_QUAD WHERE P=RI_ID))
            result (case when (dump_iri_ids) then RI_ID else RP_NAME || subseq (RI_NAME, 4) end);
        }
    }
```

Notice that the `varchar fourbytes` used for retrieving values from `RDF_IRI` is construct by bitshifting the `int` that comes the `RDF_PREFIX` table.  I'm not enough of a SQL'er to explain all the details, but it *looks* to me like the keys to `RDF_PREFIX` and `RDF_IRI` are really different kinds of `varchars`.  In `RDF_PREFIX`, the `RP_NAME` actually looks like an IRI, but `RDF_IRI`'s `RI_NAME` is just a sequence of bytes.